# Oшибка с вложенным запросом в листе полей основного запроса

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

Есть таблица вида:

```
create table table3 (
   month_id number, -- Месяц (например, 201501 - январь 2015 г)
   type_id  number, -- Признак абонента (2 значения: 1 - старый абонент, 2 - новый абонент)
   cnt      number  -- Кол-во абонентов
 )
```

Необходимо выдать результат по абонентам в следующем виде:

```
  Месяц,    Кол-во старых абонентов, Кол-во новых абонентов
```

Запрос:

```
select distinct month_id as 'Месяц'
,(select distinct month_id, SUM(cnt)
from table3
where type_id='1'
group by month_id) as 'Кол-во старых абонентов'
,(select distinct month_id, SUM(cnt)
from table3
where type_id='2'
group by month_id) as 'Кол-во новых абонентов'
from table3
```

Как избежать ошибки?

Comment: *Слабо понимаю, что сделал не так.* Да сообщение об ошибке с басурманского не перевёл, вот что. Сервер тебе говорит, что полученные в подзапросе ДВА поля он при всём желании не сумеет запихнуть в ОДНО поле выходного набора основного запроса.

Comment: А что непонятно? В select sum (cnt),  а в where связать через month. В листе select подзапрос может вернуть только одно поле и одну строчку связаную с основным запросом.

Comment: @0xdb, month - должен выдавать все значения (например у меня 3 месяца 201501, 201502, 201503)
да и поле type_id имеет два значение 1 и 2, запрос должен выдать месяц и отдельно количество новых абонентов и отдельно количество старых

Comment: А сумма зачем? В table3 значения cnt ещё не просуммированы?

Comment: @0xdb, да, действительно, сумма не целесообразна 9спутила постановка задачи), значит нужно вывести month_id, cnt1 - количество абонентов с type_id=1, cnt2  - количество абонентов с type_id=2

Comment: А какая у вас БД? Почему две метки после sql?

Comment: на домашнем пк установлен только ms sql server 2014

Comment: А oracle тогда причём здесь?

Comment: Последняя правка полезна потому, что картинки вместо текста здесь не приветствуются, но всё таки добавте сообщение об ошибке как текст (копи+паста). В oracle было бы, например: ORA-00913: too many values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По моему так:

```
insert into table3 
    select 201501, 1, 20 from dual union all
    select 201501, 2, 30 from dual union all
    select 201502, 1, 40 from dual union all
    select 201502, 2, 50 from dual union all
    select 201502, 1, 60 from dual union all
    select 201502, 2, 70 from dual
    ;

select 
    month_id as "Месяц", 
    (
        select sum (cnt) 
        from table3 s
        where type_id='1'
        and s.month_id = t.month_id) as "Колво старых абонентов", 
    (
        select sum (cnt)
        from table3 s
        where type_id='2'
        and s.month_id = t.month_id) as "Колво новых абонентов"
from table3 t
group by month_id
order by 1
;
```

Вывод:

```
     Месяц          Колво старых абонентов           Колво новых абонентов
---------- ------------------------------- -------------------------------
    201501                              20                              30
    201502                             100                             120
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Я не сделал привязку s.month_id = t.month_id

Comment: Пожалуйста! Я пока оставил sum в подзапросах, иначе надо указать первичный ключ в вопросе, который обеспечит уникальность суммы за месяц.

Answer (score 2):

Решение без вложенных подзапросов:

```
with tab (month_id, type_id, cnt) as ( 
    select 201501, 1, 20 from dual union all
    select 201501, 2, 30 from dual union all
    select 201502, 1, 40 from dual union all
    select 201502, 2, 50 from dual union all
    select 201502, 1, 60 from dual union all
    select 201502, 2, 70 from dual)


select month_id,
       sum(case when type_id = '1' then cnt else 0 end),
       sum(case when type_id = '2' then cnt else 0 end)
from tab
group by month_id
order by month_id
```